# How to Apply Source Formatting on all open documents in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, adobe, dreamweaver, web-frontend

How to Apply Source Formatting on all the open and related documents** in Adobe Dreamweaver. This could be a time savvy.

I couldn't perform **"Find all & Replace all"** operations on all open documents Successfully without this.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: You might have better luck at the Adobe forums.

Comment: I know this is old, but, I wish we could as it WOULD be a huge time saver. I have about a 100 that I need to do right now. Forums offered no help and currently are all complaining about the newer versions of Apply Source Formatting. Guess I am glad I didn't sell out to Adobe's rental software scheme.

Answer (score -1):

You can go **commands > Apply Source Formating**.

Comment: That will only do the current document,